# Are there 2 kinds of $null in PowerShell?

Tags: json, powershell, null, automation-null

I've stumbled across an odd situation in PowerShell 5.1 (Windows 10) where `ConvertTo-Json` produces `{}` instead of  `null` for an apparently null valued object:

```bsh
[CmdletBinding()]
param()
function main() {
    $foo1 = $null
    Write-Verbose ("foo1 null? " + ($null -eq $foo1))
    $foo2 = try{1/0}catch{}
    Write-Verbose ("foo2 null? " + ($null -eq $foo2))
    $foo3 = try{1/0}catch{$null}
    return [PSCustomObject]@{"foo1"=$foo1; "foo2" = $foo2; "foo3" = $foo3} | ConvertTo-Json
}
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
main
```

Running this cmdlet `-verbose` shows two apparently `$null` variables which are serialized differently by `ConvertTo-Json`:

```
VERBOSE: foo1 null? True
VERBOSE: foo2 null? True
{
    "foo1":  null,
    "foo2":  {}
    "foo3":  null
}
```

What is going on here - are there different kinds of `$null`?

I can't to `$foo2 | gm` or `$foo2.GetType()` because `$foo2` is null.

Comment: Yes, there's also an `AutomationNull`

Comment: FWIW, after this code `(New-Object psobject).GetHashCode() -eq $foo2.PSBase.GetHashCode()` (and `-eq (ConvertFrom-Json "{}").GetHashCode()`). It appears to be a "null object" which compares equal to a proper `$null` reference for most purposes due to eager unwrapping and converting, but is not actually a true, proper `$null`.

Comment: Another simple way of getting this object: `$foo2 = &{}`, that is, simply evaluate an empty scriptblock (which is what the `try`/`catch` does in a more roundabout way). It behaves as if it is `$null` in many contexts, but definitely is not `$null`.

Comment: Indeed, @JeroenMostert; a minimal reproduction is `[pscustomobject] @{ foo = . {}; bar = $null } | ConvertTo-Json`

Comment: It's interesting, though, that `ConvertTo-Json` wouldn't convert `[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value` to `$null`, as that is what usually happens.

Comment: I've opened a GitHub issue for the unexpected `ConvertTo-Json` behavior: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9231